# Laravel query showing wrong data while use where and orWhere clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
Users::where('application_ID', '=', $request->application_ID)
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('app_status','!=','')
          ->orWhere('app_status','!=','Accept')
          ->orWhere('app_status','!=','Reject')
          ->orWhere('app_status','!=','Comm Accept')
          ->orWhere('app_status','!=','Comm Reject');
})->get();
```

Output:

```
select * from `user` where `application_ID` = '0320120332330' and (`app_status` != 'Accept' or `app_status` != 'Reject' or `app_status` != 'Comm Accept' or `app_status` != 'Comm Reject')
```

In the above query if in my table I have `app_status = Accept, Reject, Comm Accept and Comm Reject` then the query return all record related to `application_ID = '0320120332330'` but I have already mention that if `app_status != Accept, Reject, Comm Accept and Comm Reject` then again it return all record. I don't know why?

Comment: You have multiple orWhere on the same column with `!=`, so you get every record. if it is "Accept" it is not "Reject" so the record is in your results... Basically 4 of the orWhere statements are always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use where not in

```
Users::where('application_ID', '=', $request->application_ID)
->whereNotIn('app_status', ['', 'Accept', 'Reject', 'Comm Accept', 'Comm Reject'])->get();
```